# Solve the vector equation

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

Solve for $\vec{r}$ where

\begin{align}
\vec{r}.\vec{n}_1&=1\\ 
\vec{r}.\vec{n}_2&=1\\
\vec{n}_1&\not=\vec{n}_2
\end{align}

I took 
$$\vec{r}=a.\vec{n}_1+b.\vec{n}_2+c.(\vec{n}_1x\vec{n}_2)$$
then 
\begin{align}
\vec{r}.\vec{n}_1=a.\vec{n}_1.\vec{n}_1+b.\vec{n}_2.\vec{n}_1&=1\\    
\vec{r}.\vec{n}_2=a.\vec{n}_1.\vec{n}_2+b.\vec{n}_2.\vec{n}_2=1   
\end{align}
Subtracting we get
$$(a.\vec{n}_1+b.\vec{n}_2).(\vec{n}_1-\vec{n}_2)=0 $$ 
I have no idea what to do next.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOM6s.jpg

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question.  Also, what are you trying to find and what is given?

Comment: I added an image to the question. I don't actually know how to use MathJax. I will definitely learn about it after my exam today. Cheers.

Comment: From your picture, I tried to format using MathJax and copied some of the questions over from your image.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Perhaps you need that $\vec{n}_1$ and $\vec{n}_2$ are not multiples of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly need that $\vec{n}_1$ and $\vec{n}_2$ are not multiples of each other (or one is not a multiple of the other, to be more precise).  If, say, $\vec{n}_2=\lambda\vec{n}_1$, then $\vec{r}.\vec{n}_2=\lambda\vec{r}.\vec{n}_1$ and they cannot both be $1$ unless $\lambda=1$.

Suppose now that neither of $\vec{n}_1$ and $\vec{n}_2$ is a multiple of the other.  Then, consider
$$
c_1(\vec{n}_1-\operatorname{proj}_{\vec{n}_2}\vec{n}_1)+c_2(\vec{n}_2-\operatorname{proj}_{\vec{n}_1}\vec{n}_2).
$$
We observe that if we take the dot product with $\vec{n}_1$, the second term disappears since we are subtracting the portion of $\vec{n}_2$ in the direction of $\vec{n}_1$.  Therefore, we are left with
$$
c_1\vec{n}_1.(\vec{n}_1-\operatorname{proj}_{\vec{n}_2}\vec{n}_1).
$$
Now, you want this to be $1$, which can happen by a good choice of $c_1$ unless 
$$
\vec{n}_1.(\vec{n}_1-\operatorname{proj}_{\vec{n}_2}\vec{n}_1)=0.
$$ 
Multiplying this out, we get
$$
|\vec{n}_1|^2-\frac{(\vec{n}_1.\vec{n}_2)^2}{|\vec{n}_2|^2}=0,
$$
or that
$$
|\vec{n}_1|^2|\vec{n}_2|^2=(\vec{n}_1.\vec{n}_2)^2.
$$
Since $\vec{n}_1.\vec{n}_2=|\vec{n}_1||\vec{n}_2|\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors, substituting this in implies that
$$
\cos^2(\theta)=1
$$
or that $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$.  Neither case is possible because then one vector is a multiple of the other.  We have a similar case when dealing with $c_2$.  Therefore,
$$
\vec{r}=\frac{\vec{n}_1-\operatorname{proj}_{\vec{n}_2}\vec{n}_1}{\vec{n}_1.(\vec{n}_1-\operatorname{proj}_{\vec{n}_2}\vec{n}_1)}+\frac{\vec{n}_2-\operatorname{proj}_{\vec{n}_1}\vec{n}_2}{\vec{n}_2.(\vec{n}_2-\operatorname{proj}_{\vec{n}_1}\vec{n}_2)}.
$$